# Sybase ASE: show the character encoding used by the database

Tags: character-encoding, sybase, database-administration, sap-ase

I am working on a Sybase ASE database and would like to know the character encoding (UTF8 or ASCII or whatever) used by the databae.

What's the command to show which character encoding the database uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're looking for is actually a system stored procedure:

```
1> sp_helpsort
2> go
... snip ...
Sort Order Description
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 Character Set = 190, utf8
     Unicode 3.1 UTF-8 Character Set
     Class 2 Character Set
 Sort Order = 50, bin_utf8
     Binary sort order for the ISO 10646-1, UTF-8 multibyte encodin
     g character set (utf8).
... snip ...
```

From this output we  see this particular ASE dataserver has been configured with a default character set of `utf8` and default sort order of `binary` (`bin_utf8`).  This means all data is stored as `utf8` and all indexing/sort operations are performed using a `binary` sort order.

Keep in mind ASE can perform character set conversions (for reads and writes) based on the client's character set configuration.  Though the successfulness of said conversions will depend on the character sets in question (eg, a client connecting with `utf8` may find many characters cannot be converted for storage in a dataserver defined with a default character set of `iso_1`).

Answer (score 2):

With a query:

```
select
cs.name as server_character_set,
cs.description as character_set_description
from
master..syscharsets cs left outer join
master..sysconfigures cfg on
    cs.id = cfg.value
where
cfg.config = 131
```

Example output:

```
server_character_set    character_set_description
utf8    Unicode 3.1 UTF-8 Character Set
```